# Еще раз о тире между подлежащим и сказуемым

Tags: тире, словосочетания, части-речи

*Дворец Топкапы – **один из лучших памятников**, отражающих классическую архитектуру Османской империи.*

Постановка тире не вызывает сомнения, но какое **правило** Розенталя следует применить?  Для этого нужно  определить **вид** сочетания "один из памятников" и, соответственно, какой частью речи является слово ***"один".***

А вот это тоже вопрос – это **числительное** или еще что (слово многозначное, всего 7 значений)?

**[Словарь](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD&mode=slovari&l=1&dicts%5B%5D=42)**  **[Ответы Mail.ru](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/190216734)**

Как ответить на все эти вопросы и правильно обосновать **выбор тире?**

**P. S.** Оборот используется **часто**, поэтому желательно иметь однозначный ответ **по этой теме.**

Answer (score 1):

1. **Какой частью речи** является слово ***"один"***?

Определяем **[по толковому словарю](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD&mode=slovari&l=1&dicts%5B%5D=42):** **ОДИН** II. **в зн. прил. 4. Определённый** (из числа однородных лиц, предметов, явлений). Одна из моих книг потеряна. Один из стульев сломан. Был один из обычных зимних дней. Поселился здесь одним из первых. Запомнил одно из тогдашних событий.

2. Сочетание ***один из памятников*** относится к  **несвободным** сочетаниям из-за наличия падежного управления и в предложении рассматривается **как единый член.** В приведенном примере это **именная часть сказуемого** при опущенной связке.
3. С точки зрения семантики ***один из памятников*** — это определенный **предмет**(памятник), взятый из последовательности однородных предметов (других памятников). Слово ***один*** стоит **в форме И.п.**
4. Соответственно, к этому случаю можно применить **[правило Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92)**, **пункт 1:** Тире ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым при отсутствии связки, если оба главных члена предложения выражены **существительными** в форме именительного падежа.

Сравнить: *Дворец Топкапы — лучший **памятник**, отражающий классическую архитектуру Османской империи.*

5. **Короткий ответ:**

Тире ставится по правилу **Розенталя**, пункт 1, так как **предложно-именное** сочетание "один из памятников" можно приравнять к **существительному** "памятник" как по смыслу, так и по грамматике.

**P. S.** Конечно, можно сказать: какая **разница** в том, числовой это оборот или предложно-именной, ведь в любом случае ставится **тире.** Да и **не заметит** никто, что именно вы сказали.

Да, скорее всего, не заметят, а могут и заметить (и тогда нужно будет объясняться). Можно что-то знать **в общих чертах**, но ваш более высокий уровень будет заметен именно **в деталях.**

Comment: Нечасто появляюсь в последнее время... Стра-анно, что *никто* до сих пор не поддержал ни ваш вопрос, ни ваш ответ. Надо это дело исправить!

Comment: Спасибо, Римма за внимание! (Голос от мня за ваш недавний ответ.) Нечасто появляетесь, да.  Но сейчас здесь многие нечасто появляются, а то и вовсе ушли. Смена поколений...  Что ж, пусть работают новые, так что я не против.  Форум прежним все равно не будет, пусть меняется.  "Золотой/классический век" позади,  но это общий закон развития. Как в литературе: на смену классике приходит модернизм и символизм) Оставлю себе чистую грамматику, а так тоже уйду.